# Simulation tool cannot recognize if pulse width smaller than delay cell in verilog

Tags: version-control, verilog, simulation

I am using VCS tool to verify for 1 AND logic cell.
I set the 2 inputs = 1 (pulse signal) with pulse width is 25ps.
Delay cell define in verilog model of cell AND is 26ps.
Because pulse width = 25ps < delay cell = 26ps so output is always 0 even that 2 input equal 1 during 25ps.
I want to ask in the real chip, Whether we can detect this pulse or not ?
Anybody can help me.

output should equal 1 for about 25ps.

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question. Are you asking if you can simulate the timing behaviour of the real chip? This can't be done through behavioural simulation, as you can in theory specify an infinite precision. Real chip have timing requirements based on the actual silicon implementation of the logic gates.

Answer (score -1):

VCS (and other simulators) have switches to control how they handle these situations.

Look at `+pulse_e`, `+pulse_r`, as well as things like `+transport_int_delays`, `+transport_path_delays`, `+pulse_on_event`, `+pulse_on_detect`, and `+delay_mode_*`, etc.

You can have the simulator propagate that short pulse (25 < 26).  You can have it propagate 1'bx, or you can have it swallow it and propagate nothing.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I can solve my issue with command "+pulse_e, +pulse_r". Now, It can work well.